# Can I use Z3Py withouth doing a system-wide install?

Tags: python, z3

I'm trying to use Z3 from its python interface, but I would prefer not to do a system-wide install (i.e. sudo make install). I tried doing a local install with a --prefix, but the Makefile is hard-coded to install into the system's python directory.

Best case, I would like run z3 directly from the build directly, in the same way I use the z3 binary (build/z3). Does anyone know how to, or have script, to run the z3py directly from the build directory, without doing an install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by including the build directory in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variables.

Comment: I made it work by exporting PYTHONPATH=/home/dejan/workspace/z3/src/api/python, and then in python doing init("/home/dejan/workspace/z3/build/libz3.so").

Comment: Dejan, if you'd add your comment as an answer, you'd have my upvote now. If you do it, answer me here, then you'll still get your upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the python interface, edit the `build/Makefile` and comment out or delete the following lines in the `install` target:

```
@cp libz3$(SO_EXT) /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libz3$(SO_EXT)
@cp z3*.pyc /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```